# Postgresql insert trigger does not work

Tags: sql, postgresql, triggers, plpgsql

New row is added to table A and i need trigger which will automatically insert row in table B after row has been inserted in table A.

```
CREATE FUNCTION insertblocked (
)
RETURNS trigger AS
$body$
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO tableB (blocked.id,blocked.number,blocked.date)
    VALUES (new.id,new.prefix,now())
    RETURN NEW;
END
$body$
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
VOLATILE
CALLED ON NULL INPUT
SECURITY INVOKER;

CREATE TRIGGER insertblocked
  AFTER INSERT 
  ON public.tableA FOR EACH ROW 
  EXECUTE PROCEDURE insertblocked();
```

Please help and advise, why is sql compiler returning and error

> QUERY:  INSERT INTO blocked (blocked.id,blocked.number,blocked.date) VALUES ( $1 , $2 ,now()) RETURN  $3

Answer (score 2):

You're missing a semi-column `;` at the end of your insert statement.